# ModuleNotFoundError and ImportError even beeing right

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux, django-models

[image]

Hello, thanks for your time.

i'm trying to import models on seeders.py.

Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong, i've done this a hundred times and tried every single way:

```
from winners.models import Player
or
from ..models import Player
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Player (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=sex_choices)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    team = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

by the way i've just started on linux may i havent set a envy variable right?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: ```
  File "/home/kali/.virtualenvs/celero/olympic/winners/seeders/seeder.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ...models import Player
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Are you importing from `seeder.py`? It is in the package `seeders` which is in a folder `winners` which is not a package (does not have `__init__.py`). Also `models.py` looks to be a part of the first package / folder in your image `OLYMPIC`. (I might be wrong here not sure your image is not very well indented)

Comment: i'm running seeder.py, winners has a __init__.py, and models.py is in winners (app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

```
from .models import Player
```

would work fine.

In detail:

In Django default relative path points to the parent folder. i.e. all the files that are in the same folder can be imported directly into each other. and dot(.) prefix is used to donate the parent of the current folder. Hence the correct code will be:

```
from .models import Player
```

Comment: from .models import Player
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

i had already tried, guess is something messing with 2.7 that already comes with linux, although i've tried to run with python3 either.

Comment: Are you running the Django server like  `python3 manage.py runserver` or something else?

Comment: the problem was i was running the seeder command wrong, should be python manage.py seeder and not python seeder.py

Answer (score 0):

Try importing `sys` module.

```
from sys import path

path.append(path_to_dir_with_module) # <- it might be loaded from ENV

# after this import your models

import models
```

If the issue is that python PATH does not contain path to your package, it should help.

Comment: don't get what path_to_dir_with_module should be, tried with winners and seeders and didnt worked